# Change makefile to work on 'make all' command

Tags: makefile

So I have completed school project on making a Sudoku program and I have this makefile which works cleanly when i use 'make' command. I just found out that I need it to compile cleanly on 'make all' command. I can't figure out how to set this up though. Any suggestions?

```
CC = gcc
OBJS = main.o MainAux.o game.o parser.o solver.o 
EXEC = sudoku_console
COMP_FLAG = -ansi -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors
GUROBI_COMP = -I/usr/local/lib/gurobi563/include
GUROBI_LIB = -L/usr/local/lib/gurobi563/lib -lgurobi56

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(GUROBI_LIB) -o $@ -lm
main.o: main.c game.h 
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) -c $*.c
game.o: game.c MainAux.h parser.h solver.h game.h
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) -c $*.c
MainAux.o: MainAux.c game.h
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) -c $*.c
parser.o: parser.c MainAux.h
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) -c $*.c
solver.o: solver.c game.h MainAux.h
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) $(GUROBI_COMP) -c $*.c
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a target named `all` that depends on whatever you want to happen.  So for example:

```
all: $(EXEC)
.PHONY: all
```

the `.PHONY` is good hygiene but not strictly required.

Now when you run `make all` it finds the `all` target, sees that in order to update it it must first update the `$(EXEC)` target, and Bob's your uncle!

Comment: Thank you, this works! I have a question though.
When I change the first target $(EXEC): $(OBJS) to all: ($OBJS) it also seems to work (and of course the executable output name). Is the effect of your proposition and this one any different?

Comment: If you do it your way and you run `make` twice in a row without changing any files, it will still re-link the program the second time (and every other time).  If you do it my way then the second (and subsequent) times it won't do anything because there's nothing to do.